# What are the differences between a h:commandButton and a a4j:commandButton in JSF?

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

Can this question be answered here? I know that for a4j:commandButton exists a relation to ajax. But when can i use h:commandButton and when it is ok to use the a4j:commandButton.

This core of this question can be refered to the h:commandLink and the a4j:commandLink.

Many thanks !
Maik

Comment: What part of the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.X/3.3.3.Final/en/devguide/html/a4j_commandButton.html) didn't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Richfaces 3.3.3 Live Demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/commandButton.jsf?tab=usage&cid=68515)

> `a4j:commandButton` is similar to the standard `h:commandButton`, but produces an Ajax request with a further partial page update. 'reRender' attribute points to the component(s) that should be re-rendered in the component tree and updated in the browser DOM after an Ajax Response is completed

In RichFaces 4

> the `a4j:commandButton` combines the standard `h:commandButton` with a4j:ajax.

When you compare VDL documentation for [a4j:commanButton](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/vdldoc/) and [h:commandButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html) then you can see some ajax related attributes in `a4j:commandButton`: `render`, `limitRender`, `onbeforedomupdate`, `onbegin`, `oncomplete` (these attributes are not part of `h:commandButton`). It means both can be used for action and page navigation, but `a4j:commandButton` has additional attributes for ajax special options (especially in case when partially page re-rendering needed).

---

Note related to Spindizzy answer:
Page navigation works fine with `a4j:commandButton` in RichFaces 3.3.x and RichFaces 4.x. If somebody has problem with page navigation using `a4j:commandButton` (in JSF 1.2 and very old RichFaces) then it can be fixed by adding `<redirect />` in `navigation-case` (**faces-config.xml**)

Answer (score 0):

The a4j:commandButton exists since version 3.0.0 of RichFaces, long time before the standard implementation supported Ajax.

I would always stick to the standard, so use the h:commandButton with Ajax support. If you can't do what you want to do with the standard, look for alternatives. The a4j button has some more features.

A usecase for a4j:commandButton would be rendering a panel when the state of a bean has changed without a complete reload of the page.

There were some [issues](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CommonAjaxRequestsProblems#navigation) related to page navigation in an older version of RichFaces.

Comment: Oh c'mon. Your link points to documents from 2011 and 2009. They both work and the RichFaces variant has convenience attributes like `oncomplete` I don't want to miss (you *can* do that with `f:ajax`, but it's a pain). Spot on with the historical perspective, tho.

Comment: @Spindizzy, your answer is wrong (at least some parts). Do you have any issues with `a4j:comandButton` for page navigation? Citation of some outdated forum post is not the best practice.

Comment: Actually you're right. If I think of it, I only used the h:commandButton for page navigation. So updated the answer.